# Memory Leak from Referenced Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, reference

I am learning about reference pointers and memory leaks.

I have created a method that takes in a pointer to a NodeData, create a Node that contains NodeData, and a left pointer, and a right pointer, and insert it depending on its value. I am using a reference pointer to traverse my tree. I am getting a memory leak every time I declare a new Node object and go outside of the scope.

I thought that since the pointer reference is pointing to the object, it has not disappeared. My program runs fine, but when I use valgrind it comes up with an error.

I have written this method multiple ways but cannot find out a way to fix it. I have posted the most concise method I've written.

```
bool BinTree::insert(NodeData* s) {
    Node* currentPtr = root;
    bool insert = insertHelper(s, currentPtr);
    return insert;
};

bool BinTree::insertHelper(NodeData* s, Node*& currentPtr) {
    if (currentPtr == NULL) {
        Node* newNodePtr = new Node;
        newNodePtr->data = s;
        newNodePtr->left = NULL;
        newNodePtr->right = NULL;
        currentPtr = newNodePtr;
        return true;
    } else if (*s == *currentPtr->data) {
        return false;
    } else if (*s < (*currentPtr->data)) {
        return insertHelper(s, currentPtr->left);
    } else {
        return insertHelper(s, currentPtr->right);
    }
}
```

I'm getting a lot of memory leaks throughout my program due to similar errors.

Or, would anyone explain the concept behind the pointer reference, or ways to learn more about it?

The method is used by this method:

```
void buildTree(BinTree& T, ifstream& infile) {                                         
    string s;                                                                                                                                                                
for (;;) {                                                                         
    infile >> s;                                                                   
    cout << s << ' ';                                                              
    if (s == "$$") break;                // at end of one line                     
    if (infile.eof()) break;             // no more lines of data                  
    NodeData* ptr = new NodeData(s);     // NodeData constructor takes string      
    // would do a setData if there were more than a string                         

    bool success = T.insert(ptr);                                                  
    if (!success)                                                                  
        delete ptr;                       // duplicate case, not inserted          
}
}
```

Comment: what exact errors does exactly show? How do you delete the nodes of your tree? Memory leak usually comes when you forget to free memory (use orerator delete)

Comment: Within `insert()` the variable `currentPtr` has automatic storage duration so ceases to exist when the function returns.   Making it point to something (by passing it to `insertHelper()`, which changes it in some circumstances, in your code) does not change that.

Comment: Sandro, our assignment does not include deletion operators. I will include the method written by my professor that uses insert.

Comment: Peter, if I just use root as the parameter instead of currentPtr, I get more memory leaks.

Comment: First goal to to get a program that works, fewer memory leaks is not a good thing if the program stops doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: John, agreed. The program works fine. I've written about 80% of the program and was reflecting on progress. my teacher is saying we will get point deductions if memory leaks.  Also I want to learn more about this and how to have a deeper understanding later on about memory storage.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the program works fine when you don't use root, the version with currentPtr is clearly an error (as Peter has also told you). But then I can't see the whole program, nor do I know what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I get less memory errors using Valgrind when I use currentPtr so I am going off of what my debugger says. I meant by 'fine' that it compiles and runs without an error. I have commented out most of my program and am working with only these methods right now. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: That sounds like a good strategy. Although you are talking about memory leaks, you haven't actually shown the part of the code where you free the memory. Maybe there is a bug there?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a bit more luck with this

```
bool BinTree::insert(NodeData* s) {
    bool insert = insertHelper(s, root);
    return insert;
};
```

Your code modified a local variable, not the root.

If you want to modify the root, you need a reference to the root, not to a local variable which has a copy of the root.

Comment: I thought that as well. I initially tried it with root but I am getting more memory leaks by using the root. I am having the leaks happen on: "Node *newNodePtr = new Node"

Comment: Would need to see a complete program to know where the leaks are.

Comment: John, I have included the method that uses the insert method. What else should I include ?

Comment: A complete program, it doesn't have to be the whole program, but it does have to be complete. Think about, how is it possible to reliably see memory leaks when you can't see a complete program? The memory could be freed in a part of the program that isn't included.

Comment: I took what you said into consideration John and so far I have seemed to fix the problem. It was in my destructor where I deleted the NodeData and the pointers but not the Node object itself. I know this is probably a rookie mistake, if not borderline noob. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me with it!

Comment: OK, that sounds like progress.

Comment: Thank you so much John! I was stuck for HOURS! you're a lifesaver lol